# Angular Charts -- How can I update labels without redrawing chart

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using Angular Chart http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/. Can I update labels without redrawing the whole chart? It's all good when I only change `data`, but every time if I update labels, chart will be rebuilt instead of partial update.

html:

```
 <div class="content-body chart-container">
                    <canvas 
                    class="chart chart-line" 
                    chart-type="line" 
                    chart-data="data"
                    chart-labels="labels" 
                    chart-options="options"
                    >
                    </canvas>
                </div>
```

controller:

```
$interval(function() {
      $scope.data = newData;
      $scope.labels = newLabels
    },1000)
```